# GameObject.transform.position not working properly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity and i want to get the position of the player so i use the code for the enemy:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObjetct player;

    void Start() 
    {
        Debug.Log(player.transform.position.x);
    }

}
```

I have a spawner and here is the code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnEnemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemy;
    float randX;
    float randY;
    Vector2 whereToSpawn;
    public float spawnRate = 2f;
    float nextSpawn = 0.0f; 


    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            randX = Random.Range(-6.36f, 6.36f);
            randY = Random.Range(-4.99f, 4.99f);
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, randY);
            Instantiate (enemy, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run it, it always gives me (0, 0, 0). Why do i get 0 and how can i fix it ( get the current position of the player )?

Comment: Where how is the `player` assigned? Is it the correct object? It sounds like it refers to a prefab ....

Answer (score 0):

Probably your player variable of enemy is not correctly assigned.

Try to assign the player GameObject variable to your SpawnEnemies object, and let this one assign the player variable to the enemies script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnEnemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemy;
    float randX;
    float randY;
    Vector2 whereToSpawn;
    public float spawnRate = 2f;
    float nextSpawn = 0.0f; 

    public GameObject player = null; //Remember to assign this through the editor!

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            randX = Random.Range(-6.36f, 6.36f);
            randY = Random.Range(-4.99f, 4.99f);
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, randY);
            GameObject enemy = Instantiate (enemy, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
            enemy.player = this.player; //here you can assign to each new created enemy your player position on runtime.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Probably your player variable of enemy is not assigned.` wouldn't this rather throw a `NullReferenceException` and not return `0,0,0`?

Comment: true, the sentence should be "is not correctly assigned", edited, thanks @derHugo

Comment: In fact it sounds (and looks) like `player` refers to a prefab => never moving in the scene